# MongoDB Aggregation : Group on common field of two arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is a sample document:

```
{
    'uid': 1,
    'sent': [
        {
            'mid': 100,
            'date': 20171210,
        },
        {
            'mid': 101,
            'date': 20171210,
        }
    ],
    'open': [
        {
            'mid': 100,
            'date': 20171220,
        },
        {
            'mid': 101,
            'date': 20171220,
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to group on **'uid'** and nested **'mid'** fields.
My desired output is :

```
{
    'uid': 1,
    'mid': 100,
    'sent': [ 20171210 ],
    'open': [ 20171220 ]
}
{
    'uid': 1,
    'mid': 101,
    'sent': [ 20171210 ],
    'open': [ 20171220 ]
}
```

Is there any efficient way of Aggregation which can give me above result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the one array, then use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) to keep only the matching entries in the second array. Then $unwind the second array and $group.

```
db.temp.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $unwind: {
                'path': '$sent',
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                'uid': 1,
                'sent': 1,
                'open': { $filter: {
                                    input: '$open',
                                    as: 'this',
                                    cond: { $eq: [ '$sent.mid', '$$this.mid' ] }
                               } }

            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                'path': '$open',
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                '_id': { 'uid': '$uid', 'mid': '$sent.mid' },
                'sent': { '$push': '$sent.date' },
                'open': { '$push': '$open.date' }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                '_id': 0,
                'uid': '$_id.uid',
                'mid': '$_id.mid',
                'sent': 1,
                'open': 1
            }
        },
    ]
);
```